# Add a handler to allow dowloading script or a MIME map

Tags: asp.net, iis

I created a script for Internet Explorer which can be installed using GM4IE (Greasemonkey for Internet Explorer) and it has the extension .gm4ie.

When I try to give the download link to this file on my server, it gives this error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7Rs4.jpg

> page you are requesting cannot be
>   served because of the extension
>   configuration. If the page is a
>   script, add a handler. If the file
>   should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

How do I add this this hanlder or a mime map and where do I add this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a MIME type to IIS.

For IIS7: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608(WS.10).aspx

You can of course just zip it if you don't wish to add the MIME type.

Comment: But this is no the hosting proivers' server, not on my local IIS